# How to prevent CasperJS navigating iframes?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

CasperJS will auto detect iframes and navigate to its url then sometimes crash.

Is there any config or method I can prevent casperjs navigate to iframe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can abort any network request from the ["resource.requested" event](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-resource-requested). If you know the iframe URL, then this can be applied.